# how to use nest loop in ansible playbook with json register

Tags: json, ansible

I get an complex json from an rb ,and I register like this

```
- name: get the json
  command: /abc/get_info.rb
  register: JsonInfo
```

and the json is like this

```
{"a-b-c.abc.com":[["000000001","a"],["000000002","a"],["000000003","c"]],"c-d-e.abc.com":[["000000010","c"],["000000012","b"]],"c-d-m.abc.com":[["000000022","c"],["000000033","b"],["000000044","c"]]}
```

but what I can do is just output the json like this:

```
- debug: msg="{{JsonInfo}}"
```

and loop like this

```
- debug: msg="{{item.key}} and the host is{{inventory_hostname}} and value is{{item.value}}"
  with_dict: "{{JsonInfo.stdout}}" 
  when: item.key==inventory_hostname
```

by the way ,the a-b-c.abc.com,c-d-e.abc.com,c-d-m.abc.com is hostname of server

but what I really want to do is to run a loop on the json first,and get the result of

```
"a-b-c.abc.com":[["000000001","a"],["000000002","a"],["000000003","c"]]
"c-d-e.abc.com":[["000000010","c"],["000000012","b"]]
"c-d-m.abc.com":[["000000022","c"],["000000033","b"],["000000044","c"]]
```

and when I got all these above ,I run another loop for each of the value of a-b-c.abc.com,c-d-e.abc.com,c-d-m.abc.com and then according to the "a","c" ,run different commmand on the a-b-c.abc.com or c-d-e.abc.com

How Can I loop those json ?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with [the available Ansible loops](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html). You can archive this by [creating your own lookup plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_plugins.html#lookup-plugins).